# Logstash http input plugin - Connection Refused

Tags: http, logstash, logstash-configuration

Using `Logstash 1.5.4` version. `Http input plugin` connecting to `localhost` with port `2099`.

`Tomcat` is web application server. Ouput gets indexed to `Elasticsearch`.

**Error scenario:**
 When Tomcat is up and logstash is down and provide a hit to localhost:2199 with a message to be indexed into ES from my application, getting `connection refused` error.

**Question:** How to verify if the `localhost:2199` is already up before sending events via HTTP POST method to logstash input?
Can this verification be done with configuration change?

Answer (score 0):

The http input plugin will, when running, listen to the defined port and accept events that way.  If it's not running, it's up to whatever is sending data to retry/buffer/etc.  What you've described is not a logstash problem.

Comment: Thanks @Alain Collins . Is there a way to ensure if the specific end point available in configuration of logstash?

Comment: When you ask logstash to listen on a port, it will certainly try to do it for you.  There are plenty of reasons why it might fail (insufficient privileges, port already open, out of system resources, etc).  When your code tries to connect, it can detect the failure and error out, retry, etc.